# how to debug OpenCL kernel code with Nvidia graphic card?

Tags: debugging, opencl, nvidia

How to debug OpenCL kernel code with Nvidia graphic card ? 
Suggest me some debugger if any has been upgraded to support opencl and nvidia graphic card.

Answer (score 1):

What you want:[Nvidia Visual Profiler](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/nvidia-visual-profiler)
(Thanks google)

Comment: NVIDIA Nsight for Visual Studio (not Express edition) or Eclipse: [link](http://developer.nvidia.com/content/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition)

Comment: Please give me a straight forward answer.. Can I debug OpenCL kernel source code with NVIDIA Nsight ?

Comment: No, at the moment (v5.0) it only supports CUDA. And AMDs tools only support AMD GPUs.

Comment: @AlexPlacet This is not an OpenCL debugger.